# Using LINQ to SQL group, sum and aggreate all together

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables Students and Origami. Origami has Foreign Key of Students table. Each student can make one or more origami for each month.

Students sample data:

StudentId, FirstName, LastName

- 187 , John ,  Maslow
- 196 , Crystal , Hood
- 195 , Sarah , Lewis

Origami sample data:

OrigamiId, StudentId, CreationDate, NumberOfOrigami

- 1 , 187 ,    5/17/2010 1:06:55 PM , 1
- 2 , 196 ,    5/22/2010 1:31:28 PM  , 2
- 3 ,  187 ,   6/18/2010 1:51:40 PM , 2
- 4 ,  187 ,   6/19/2010 2:13:35 PM , 1
- 5 ,  196 ,   7/17/2010 2:19:44 PM , 3
- 6 ,  196 ,   7/19/2010 2:23:02 PM , 2
- 7 ,  195 ,   7/20/2010 3:04:15 PM , 3

and many more records like that format.

I'd like to ge the total number of origami of each student monthly. Something that looks like the following:

- Name ,Jan/2010 , Feb/2010 and so on
- John Maslow , 2 , 3
- Crystal Hood , 4 , 5
- Sarah Lewis , 6 , 5

Thanks.

> **Update One**

```
    Dim query = From st In db.Students _
                 Join or In db.Origami On or.StudentId Equals st.StudentId _
                 Group By or.StudentId Into TotalOrigami = Sum(or.NumberOfOrigami) _
                 Select StudentId, TotalOrigami
```

This query give only total origami of each student. But I want monthly count of origami for each student. Any suggestion is welcom.

Comment: Please see my Update One. I included the query I tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working query:

```
Dim query = From st In db.Students _ 
                 Join ori In db.Origami On ori.StudentId Equals st.StudentId _ 
                 Group By key = New With {ori.Student, .MonthYear = (ori.CreationDate.Value.Month & "/" & tr.CreationDate.Value.Year)}  Into TotalOrigami = Sum(ori.NumberOfOrigami) _ 
                 Select key.Student.FirstName,key.Student.LastName,key.MonthYear,TotalOrigami
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an extra property that only holds the Month/Year on the origami object. and then use the query below

```
            var q = from st in db.Students 
                    join or in db.Origami on or.StudentId equals st.StudentID
                    group st by new { st.StudentId, or.MonthYear } into g
                    select new { g.Key.StudentId, g.Key.MontYear, Total = g.Count() };
```

I just saw that the example is in C# but I hope you will get through.

Comment: Can give me the link to example you just saw? Thx.

Comment: I created it myself with a couple of articles and a testproject of myself

Comment: I used these articles: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/07/group-by-multiple-columns-in-linq-to-sql.aspx   and   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737926.aspx#grpbymult